# PHP - Unable to echo $row

Tags: php, html, mysql, email

I am trying to setup email notifications for a webform:

```
$query = "UPDATE email_tbl SET notified='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$notified)."', reasoning='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$reasoning)."' WHERE id='$id'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$query2 = "SELECT `or_user` FROM `usf_tbl` WHERE `id` = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

$to = "example@email.com, $row[or_user]";
$subject = "Email Notification";
$message = "

<html>
<p>Email Notification for $row[or_user]</p>
</html>";
```

I am receiving the email as required, but the email doesn't contain the "or_user". However, the email is sent to the "or_user" as desired. 
Why won't it print the "or_user" in the actually email?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The keyword in $query2 should be "SELECT", no?

Comment: `$query2 = "SELECTED `or_user` FROM `usf_tbl` WHERE `id` = $id";` change to `select`

Comment: What is `SELECTED` ??

Comment: that was a typo, sorry

Comment: Your while-loop should use curly braces to keep control that not only the following row gets executed.

Comment: @JohnTemple make it correct to = "example@email.com, ".$row["or_user"]; and $message = "

<html>
<p>Email Notification for ".$row["or_user"]."</p>
</html>";

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: A while loop without `{}` will execute only the next line of PHP script after the while. So your while loop is running this `while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $to = "example@email.com, $row[or_user]";` ___And thats all___

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "UPDATE email_tbl SET notified='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$notified)."', reasoning='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$reasoning)."' WHERE id='$id'";

$result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$query2 = "SELECT `or_user` FROM `usf_tbl` WHERE `id` = $id";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     $to = "example@email.com, $row['or_user']";
     $subject = "Email Notification";
     $message = "

       <html>
            <p>Email Notification for". $row['or_user']."</p>
       </html>";
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't print the or_user

Comment: put `<?php echo $row[or_user]; ?>`

Comment: Better. But as per another question, the while-loop really isn't necessary in this case since the query should only return one result.

Answer (score 2):

Use    `mysqli_num_rows` to check weather query return result or not

```
$query2 = "SELECT `or_user` FROM `usf_tbl` WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$email = "";
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row_cnt > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

//fetch data without using  while loop

```
    $email = $row['or_user'];
    $to = "example@email.com, $email";// pass $email here
    $subject = "Email Notification";
```

// use `sprintf` to pass email into message as

```
$message = sprintf("<html>
<p>Email Notification for %s</p>
</html>", $email);
}//end if condition here
```